# Using methods from two different scopes?

Tags: ruby

How do I use methods from two different namespaces?

```
class Bar
  def self.configure &block
    new.instance_eval &block
  end

  def method2
    puts "from Bar"
  end
end

class Foo
  def method1
    puts "from Foo"
  end

  def start
    Bar.configure do
      method1
      method2
    end
  end
end

Foo.new.start
```

In the above example the method1 can't be called because it is not from the Bar scope. How do I make methods from both scopes callable at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to forward missing method calls to the instance of `Foo`:

```
class Bar
    def self.configure(&block)
        o = new
        context = eval('self', block.binding)

       class << o; self; end.send(:define_method, :method_missing) do |meth, *args|
           context.send(meth, *args)
       end

       o.instance_eval &block
    end

    def method2
        puts "from Bar"
    end
end

class Foo
    def method1
        puts "from Foo"
    end

   def start
       Bar.configure do
           method1
           method2
       end
   end
end

Foo.new.start #=> "from Foo"
              #=> "from Bar"
```

Comment: +1 for the context.send trick. Will this continue to work if Bar also had a method1?

Comment: @Sudhanshu, yes, but `method1` in `Bar` will get precedence

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Bar                              
  def initialize(foo)
    puts "init"
    @f = foo 
  end 

  def self.configure(foo, &block)
    new(foo).instance_eval &block
  end 

  def method2
    puts "from Bar"
  end 
end 

class Foo 
  def method1
    puts "from Foo"
  end 

  def start
    Bar.configure(self) do
      @f.method1
      method2
    end 
  end 
end
```

This makes @f a class level instance variable of Bar, which is set when you initialize an object of Bar using new(foo) in Bar.configure. The block being passed assumes the existence of @f, which contains a reference to the object of class Foo.

It's a convoluted way of doing this - I can't think of anything better though. It'd be interesting to know the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this is the easiest way. It doesn't need to modify Bar.

```
class Bar
  def self.configure &block
    new.instance_eval &block
  end

  def method2
    puts "from Bar"
  end
end

class Foo
  def method1
    puts "from Foo"
  end

  def start
    foo = self # add
    Bar.configure do
      foo.method1 # modify
      method2
    end
  end
end

Foo.new.start
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your code as follows:

```
class Bar
  def self.configure &block
    obj = new
    block.call(obj)
    obj
  end

  def method2
    puts "from Bar"
  end
end

class Foo
  def method1
    puts "from Foo"
  end

  def start
    Bar.configure do |obj|
      method1
      obj.method2
    end
  end
end

Foo.new.start
```

Block logic is clean and implementation doesn't require context switching. You are using the standard ruby functionality of passing parameters to the block.